# Javascript Toggle open by width

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have actually an Simple/Standart Toggle System from Bootstrap, my Knowledge about Javascript is 0, what i want is following, if the width size min. 700px then everytime open else the standart system. I Need only the function if desktop/media width size min. 700px so stay it open.

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

Comment: At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: We need more context.

Comment: ill tryd it so :
        `        if ($("#wrapper").width() > 800 ) {
           $("#wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
        }`

Answer (score 0):

My Bad! Syntax error in my code before thats the right way

```
<script>
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});

function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() > 614) {
     $('#wrapper').removeClass('toggled');
    }
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    $(window).resize(resize);
    resize();
});
</script>
```